# What's happening with array.last[x]?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I came across this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a.last # => 7
a.last[-1] # => 0
a.last[0] # => 1
a.last[1] # => 1 
a.last[100] # => 0
```

Can someone explain what's happening and why?

Comment: That's [`Fixnum#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D): `7[-1]`, `7[1]`, `7[100]`, returning the number's nth bit

Comment: so it is, thanks a lot! (stefan i'll give you the credit if you want to add an answer)

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing it with `last(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#last` returns the last element, i.e. `7`. Appending `[]` simply calls [`Fixnum#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D), returning the number's nth bit:

```
7[0]   # => 1
7[1]   # => 1 
7[2]   # => 1 
7[3]   # => 0
# ... 
7[100] # => 0

7.to_s(2) #=> "111"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the n-th bit of a number using the operator `[]` on a Fixnum. Thus you are first taking the last value in the array and then you are listing its bits. Negative index bits are always 0.